# Assigning arguments for a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, arguments

can anyone help me with this code? I cannot figure out what argument to use on `compare_all_min ()` and `compare_all_max ()`. My code is:

```
while (count <= 10) {

    minimum = getMin ( item [count] );
    maximum = getMax ( item [count] );
    printf ( "Minimum is %d\n", &min );
    pritnf ( "Max: %d\n", &max );
    count++;
}

printf ( "Displaying summary:\n" );
least_num = compare_all_min (  );         //what argument do I  
greatest_num = compare_all_max (  );      //use on these two?
printf ( "The least number contained by the array is: %d\n", &least_num );
printf ( "The greatest number contained by the array is: %d\n", &greatest_num );
```

I can't figure out what argument to use especially since there are 10 minimum numbers and 10 maximum numbers that the while loop would print out. **NOTE:** Basically, `compare_all_min ( )` just compares all the 10 minimum values that would be obtained in the while loop then get the minimum among those values, and `compare_all_max ( )` compares all the 10 maximum values and then get the maximum among those numbers. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Neither function is even *needed*. You acquire them inline with your previous while-loop, readjusting each time their respective limits are surpassed by the current number being processed. Ex: `if (minimum < least_num) least_num = minimum;` Just make sure they start out with the first initial minimum and maximum before the while-loop is started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for suppose you have arry with 10 elements then pass array to the function

```
int min[10]={10,2,34..};//10 numbers

least_num = compare_all_min ( min );
```

sample code with three Numbers:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
int min[3]={10,2,34};//10 numbers
int least_num;
least_num = compare_all_min ( min );

printf("%d\n",least_num);
}

int compare_all_min (int *array)
{
int i,least;
least=array[0];

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
if(least > array[i])
least=array[i];
return least;

}
```

Comment: Initially, I was thinking the same thing about storing those 10 minimum and maximum values into another array. Didn't know it was actually correct (sorry I'm new at this). Thanks, man.

Comment: @Sakamoto with out storing them.we are unable to  pass them to any function.if you don't want to store them,you can directly find the least_num while scaning. get the input and checks with least_num.for that read first time into least number.and then read second time onwards into another  variable lets say min .then compare if (least_num > min ) least_num=min; read min 9 times. with while loop by using counter variable .

Comment: As much as I prefer to not store them (since it would make the task pretty easier), I'm required to. So yeah.

Comment: @Sakamoto then you can try as above said. read to least_num; i=0;while(i<9){//read to min; condition and assignment based on condition;  i++;}.that's it...